# ANDROID Sign APK: FORGOT key password.

Tags: android, passwords, keystore

I want sign an APK with a keystore but I dont remember the key password

- I have the keystore file
- I have the keystore password
- I have the alias name
- I DONT have the key password (alias one)

Its possible get the alias password without bruteforce?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Only bruteforce http://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/  only hardcore

Answer (score -1):

Yes - you can restore your 'passwords.txt' from backup and look for the password there.

Seriously, the hypothetical possibility to restore the passowrd without long and expensive bruteforce - will brake the cryptography completely.